# MEF/WebAPI Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mef, self-hosting

I am working with MEF and WebAPI (Self-hosted), and I have noticed some strange behavior that I can't figure out.

This interface/class is in a separate class library assembly.

```
public interface IQueryEngine
{
    IEnumerable<T> Get<T>();
}

[Export("QueryEngine" ,typeof(IQueryEngine))]
public class QueryEngine : IQueryEngine
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>() 
    {
        // T is object instead of ManagedElementDTO - ?
        return new ManagedElementDTO();
    }
}
```

This controller is in  a WebAPI project:

```
[Export]
public class ComputerSystemController : ApiController
{
    [Import("QueryEngine", RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    private IQueryEngine _engine;

    // GET api/ComputerSystem
    public IEnumerable<ManagedElementDTO> GetComputerSystems()
    {
        var result = _engine.Get<ManagedElementDTO>();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Both projects have references to the class library containing `ManagedElementDTO`.

When the call is made to `QueryEngine.Get()`, the generic type parameters are "object" instead of `"ManagedElementDTO"`. Can you tell me why this is happening? What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the _engine.Get is correct? Itshouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

As Panos implied, your syntax seems to be wrong. I'm not a C# developer, but I believe your call to `Get` should look like this:

```
var result = _engine.Get<ManagedElementDTO>();
```

T is `object` because no type is being explicitly passed, and nothing but `object` can be inferred.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I corrected the typo. I get "object" when the type parameter is passed in.